# exports is not defined when running node.js script using vm in strict mode

Tags: node.js, node-modules, strict-mode

I see this code in many modules:

```
var app = exports = module.exports = {};
```

But I have some problem executing these modules using [Node.js VM](https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html) in strict mode.

Here a demonstration:

```
var code = `
'use strict'; // Works if I remove this line
var app = exports = module.exports;
`;

var vm = require('vm');
var vmModule = { exports: {} };
var context = vm.createContext({
  exports: vmModule.exports,
  module: vmModule
});
var script = new vm.Script(code);

script.runInContext(context);
console.log("ok");
```

If I run this code I receive a `exports is not defined` error.
Without `use strict` the above code works fine.

Why a similar declaration works on a standard Node module but not inside a vm script? Should I declare the context in a different way?

Comment: See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5344. Apparently still an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by @mscdex this is probably an issue with node. See [github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5344](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5344).

A possible workaround that seems to work (I hope without other implications) is to wrap all code inside an iife function:

```
const iifeCode = `(function(exports){${code}}(module.exports));`;
```

Then execute `iifeCode` instead of `code`:

```
var script = new vm.Script(iifeCode);
```